# dynamic subfolders in cronjob backup script

Tags: bash, cron, backup, subdirectory

I use Rclone for a backup-script for a WordPress and next cloud backup. After a lot of trials and errors, the script runs flawlessly when started from the bash. But when I run it via a cronjob newly added subfolders in the backup folder aren't included in the backup.

I added the PATH in the crontable and in the script.
I can't imagine that is would be the only solution to add every new folder into PATH - this wouldn't be an unattended backup solution.

Could you give me a hint where to look or what to do?

Thanks in advance and best regards,
Peter

Comment: One thing, if you are working cron, always give absolute path to binaries. use `which` command to findout absolute path of the binaries.

Comment: Thank you very much  for your suggestion @Ten-Coin! I also tested it with absolute paths - it won't run either via cron. I'm completly puzzled.

Comment: Do you have a shebang and is it #!/bin/bash - or whatever your path to the bash is? If not - how does crontab invoke the script? With whole filename? With a bash or sh call and the script as parameter? How do you successfully start it from the shell?